# MySQL/SQL prevent deleting records that are use in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row, sql-delete

The structure of the Two tables is as follows:

```
use exercise;

create table Companies 
(
    ID  int,
    Name    varchar(100),
    City    varchar(100),
    c_size varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

insert into Companies(ID, Name, city, company_size) 
values
(222, 'Karma LLC','CITY2', 'big'),
(223, 'Manny Ind.','CITY1', 'medium'),
(224, 'Random PLC','CITY1', 'medium'),
(225, 'Hijack LLC','CITY1', 'medium'),
(226, 'Travels LLC','CITY1', 'small'),
(227, 'Mirana Ind.','CITY2', 'small'),
(228, 'Polla Ind.','CITY3', 'small'),
(229, 'Americano LLC','CITY3', 'small'),
(230, 'Macaroni LLC','CITY4', 'small');

CREATE TABLE INVOICES
(
    ID INT auto_increment,
    `DATE` DATE,
    Company INT,
    Amount DECIMAL(7,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO INVOICES(`DATE`,Company,Amount)
VALUES
('2014-01-02', 222, 19500.00),
('2014-01-02', 222, 29205),
('2014-01-07', 222, 152.50),
('2014-01-07', 223, 6590),
('2014-01-07', 223, 4999),
('2014-01-09', 224, 720.60),
('2014-01-09', 225, 1100),
('2014-02-05', 226, 885),
('2014-02-05', 222, 9678.7);
```

As you can see, some company paid invoices, some not. I want to know the way to prevent deleting companies, that paid invoice. For example, company Americano LLC (229) can be deleted, but Karma LLC not.

The answer may be just description how, not necessery query code.
I'm not sure if it can be done by setting foreign key or trigger maybe something else?.
Sorry if I spammed stackoverflow with duplicate, but I'm a bit tired (2 a.m. here), but can't sleep because of it. I will delete it tomorrow if needed.
Sorry for poor English :(

Answer (score 2):

Foregin key will deny deletion of row, which is used in other table. Just change `Company` to be Foregin Key of `Companies.ID`